# How to control Concurrency to update 3 database tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

When i click save button on the form

it calls 3 methods:

```
save_Purchase();
save_dtPurcaseProduct();
save_dtPurchaseProductExp();
```

these 3 methods save changes to 3 database tables

so the scenario is that either all the 3 tables should be updated or none should get the update.

i am using C# and Microsoft sql server as database

Comment: You need to surround those methods with a database transaction. But when you ask a question here, you need to say what language & means to access the DB you are using. Otherwise, how can we help you?

Comment: thank u for yr reply
i use C# and Microsoft sql database
can u show me how with sample code

Comment: Could you provide the contents of the save_ methods?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to rewrite your functions, you can use [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx):

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        save_Purchase();
        save_dtPurcaseProduct();
        save_dtPurchaseProductExp();

        scope.Complete(); //All goes well, then commit your transaction
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         //Do not call complete, on exit of transactionscope, transaction will rollback
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a bad solution, if the existing methods are compatible. +1!

Answer (score 0):

All the update statements must be inside `transaction` . [More](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4451/SQL-Server-Transactions-and-Error-Handling)

If you are using `Stored procedure` Use the following method for writing stored procedure. i.e. all the three `Update` statements `inside a single transaction`. So that you can commit it if everything get updated otherwise it will be roll backed

```
CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE Proc_Name
AS
BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRAN

-- Your Update Statements

     COMMIT TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

If you are using SQL queries and ADO

Use the following methode

```
private static void Update() 
   {
      SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection("strConectionString");
      SqlTransaction transaction;

      db.Open();
      transaction = db.BeginTransaction();
      try 
      {
         new SqlCommand("update quey1", db, transaction)
            .ExecuteNonQuery();
         new SqlCommand("update quey2", db, transaction)
            .ExecuteNonQuery();
         new SqlCommand("update quey3", db, transaction)
            .ExecuteNonQuery();
         transaction.Commit();
      } 
      catch (SqlException sqlError) 
      {
         // always log or rethrow exceptions!
         transaction.Rollback();
         db.Close();
         //
         throw;
      }
      db.Close();
   }
```

[Edited]
When you do get a failure, you should always either log (if you can handle it) or ret-throw it. Otherwise, exception traces & critical diagnostic info will just be swallowed inside the 'catch` block.

In this case, I'd suggest re-throwing outwards -- since the outermost system or application thread should handle the exception, and log it at that point. If an exception occurs the update has obviously failed & the business-logic should not continue.

Comment: No need to catch specific exception if you are not doing anything with it. And you need to rethrow it as well. I have edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending 3 calls to the database. You should write one stored procedure that perform all the 3 functions for you. And you should apply transaction there. [How to implement transaction in stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx).

In case you want to keep the 3 methods then you can also apply transaction on code level.

```
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Your Connection string");
      conn.Open()
      using (SqlTransaction tran = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
      try {
      // your code
      tran.Commit();
      }  catch {
       tran.Rollback();
       throw;
      }
      }
```

Comment: I don't like stored procedures, where there isn't a real legacy-compatibility or database performance reason. They're not portable, visible, or easy to debug/ maintain.

Comment: That is one's own choice. I have given the other solution as well.

Comment: Yes, you made some good points regarding exceptions. Thanks!